# JQuery: programatically added anchors aren't associated with my click function

Tags: jquery, anchor, html

I'm new to JQuery and I'm trying to use it to implement an enhancement in an old web application.

I'm gathering a list of strings from a server and rendering each one of them in its own anchor tag such that they appear in a comma delimited list.  I assign that generated markup to a span's inner html:

```
$.getJSON("http://domain/restOfURL",
    function(data){
        var anchorString = "";
        $.each(data.companies, function(i,companies){                                    
            if (i > 0)
            {
                anchorString += ", ";
            }
            anchorString += '<a class="sr" href="#">' + companies + '</a>';
        });
        $("#anchorsListSpan").html(anchorString);
    });
});
```

All of that works and I can see the anchors on the live web page.  The markup looks like this in Firebug:

```
<span id="anchorsListSpan">
    <a class="sr" href="#">ABC</a>
    ,
    <a class="sr" href="#">Apple</a>
    ,
    <a class="sr" href="#">Apollo</a>
</span>
```

The problem I'm having is that any generated anchors are not causing my click event to fire:

```
$("a.sr").click(function(){
    alert("link clicked");
});
```

I noticed that if I hard code similar anchors within that div that the click event does fire.  For some reason the ones that I programmatically add won't cause the click event to fire.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 3):

Use live() instead of click():

```
$("a.sr").live("click", function(){
    alert("link clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$("a.sr").live('click', function() {//...});`